# Erro FATAL EXCEPTION ao carregar galeria de imagens usando AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, imagem

Estou criando uma pequena galeria e estou tendo dificuldades para carregar as imagens usando o AsyncTask

class adapter:

```
public class AdapterGaleriaFragment extends BaseAdapter {
Context ctx;
List<ImageDataModel> lista;
public AdapterGaleriaFragment(Context ctx, List <ImageDataModel> lista){
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.lista = lista;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return lista != null ? lista.size():0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return lista.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.layout_adapter, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        view = convertView;
        holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
    }
    ImageDataModel img = lista.get(position);
    loadBitmap(img.getImagePath(),holder.imgView);
    return view;
}
public void loadBitmap(String path, ImageView view) {
    Task task = new Task(view);
    task.execute(path);
}
}
```

classe do AsyncTask:

```
public class Task extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
public Task(ImageView imageView) {
    // Use a WeakReference to ensure the ImageView can be garbage collected
    imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
}

@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
    File file = new File(params[0]);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());

    return bitmap;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap){
    if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
        final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
        if (imageView != null) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Log:

> ```
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
> Process: com.example.alex_sama.galeriramesmo, PID: 25570
> java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
> at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
> at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
> Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 3686412 byte allocation with 2714916 free bytes and 2MB until OOM
> at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
> at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
> at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal(BitmapFactory.java:635)
> at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:611)
> at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:391)
> at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:417)
> at com.example.alex_sama.galeriramesmo.Task.doInBackground(Task.java:29)
> at com.example.alex_sama.galeriramesmo.Task.doInBackground(Task.java:19)
> at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
> at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
> ```

Comment: não seria isso? `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 3686412 byte allocation with 2714916 free bytes and 2MB until OOM at `

Comment: sim, como posso resolver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua implementação fatalmente falhará em imagens grandes e/ou muitas imagens. Você precisa usar um componente de lista que implemente reciclagem dos itens exibidos/não exibidos na tela, bem como facilitar sua vida com uma biblioteca de carregamento de imagens.

O simples ato de carregar uma imagem em um `ImageView` é infinitamente mais complexo no android do que se imagina. Você precisa se preocupar com rotações da tela (mudanças de orientação irão destruir o contexto em que você está carregando a imagem), leitura em background não é simples de implementar corretamente, e é necessário reduzir o tamanho da imagem carregada para um tamanho que caiba na memória e seja compatível com o tamanho do `ImageView` destino, etc.

Resolva sua vida usando ou Glide, do próprio Google, ou Picasso, da square. Eu sugiro Glide.

Além disso mude seu projeto para usar `RecyclerView`, que implementará reciclagem dos seus objetos `ViewHolder`, gastando memória apenas para as imagens exibidas na tela.

Um bom tutorial, embora em inglês: http://www.androidhive.info/2016/04/android-glide-image-library-building-image-gallery-app/

Para saber mais sobre o Glide: https://github.com/bumptech/glide (role para baixo, pois o "readme" da biblioteca está abaixo do código)

Para conhecer a biblioteca Picasso, que é uma alternativa tão boa quanto: http://square.github.io/picasso/ (vale a pena ler para ver como é mais complexo do que parece exibir imagens no android)

---

Isto posto, apenas modificar o seu código para usar Glide ou Picasso já irá, muito provavelmente, evitar o problema de falta de memória.

Adicione o Glide ao seu projeto no gradle:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
}
```

Modifique o carregamento da imagem no seu código para:

```
@Override public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.layout_adapter, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        view = convertView;
        holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
    }
    ImageDataModel img = lista.get(position);

    // não precisa se preocupar, pois o Glide já faz em background
    Glide
        .with(holder.imgView.getContext())
        .load(img.getImagePath())
        .centerCrop()
        .into(holder.imgView);

    return view; 
}
```

Comment: muito obrigado, irei ler o tutorial e testar o código acima. Esse Glide ele é parecido com o Picasso que implementa cache automático?

Comment: Sim, como disse são equivalentes, mas o glide é feito por pessoal do Google.

Answer (score 0):

Voce pode mudar o tamanho da memória heap do android utilizando o seguinte comando no seu manifest.xml   `android:largeHeap="true"`

Comment: isso não vai consumir muito a memória?

Comment: só o necessário para caber o seu objeto

Comment: ainda assim não funcionou, continua com o mesmo erro de antes